# Calling constructor with class member, C++

Tags: c++, constructor

SOLVED: used anonymous class instances:

```
particle p1(vec(0,0,0),vec(1,0,0),vec(-0.5,0,0),1)
```

creates the vec instances just to construct the particle instance.

I'm writing a little program for physics and I'm using vectors (in the math sense). The vector looks like

```
class vec {
public:
    double x, y, z;
    vec() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    vec(double xi, double yi, double zi) : x(xi), y(yi), z(zi) {}
};
```

so I can create a vector like a(1,0,-1). In a different object, I have

```
class particle {
public:
    double mass;
    vec pos, vel, acc;
    particle(vec posi, vec veli, vec acci, double m){
        pos = posi; vel = veli; acc = acci; mass = m;
    }
};
```

I'm not sure how to construct an instance of the particle class. I tried

```
particle p1((0,0,0),(1,0,0),(-0.5,0,0),1);
```

but I get an error: no known conversion from double to vec.

Comment: You might want to include what language this is.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call an constructor. You just call it like this `class_name(parameters, ...)`

In your specific case it would look like this:

```
particle p1(vec(0, 0, 0), vec(1, 0, 0), vec(-0.5, 0, 0), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're in fact calling the comma operator. [Here is a quick example](http://ideone.com/zzkPl9):

```
cout << (0, 1, 2) << endl;
```

prints 2. There are [plenty of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+comma+operator) on the subject.

One solution is indeed to use `particle p1(vec(0,0,0),vec(1,0,0),vec(-0.5,0,0),1)` and create anonymous object.

An alternative syntax was introduced in C++11 that consists in using curly braces like this:

```
particle p1({0,0,0}, {1,0,0}, {-0.5,0,0}, 1)
```

It's exactly the same thing but less verbose.

Answer (score -1):

You appear to have misplaced a parenthesis, a variable declaration, a parameter, and some instantiations.

Try:

```
particle p1 = new particle(new vec(0,0,0),new vec(1,0,0),new vec(-0.5,0,0),0);
```

Comment: So it turns out something like that works.

    particle p1(vec(0,0,0),vec(1,0,0),vec(-0.5,0,0),1);

gets the job done with anonymous vec variables.

Comment: This won't work since the constructor of `particle` doesn't accept `vec`-pointes!

Comment: Why `new` - why not use values normally? Why add the burden of heap memory management unnecessarily?